# How do i parse a very large json response returned from an API call

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm accessing data from an API endpoint using curl in my laravel application, which returns a very large JSON response. When I decode this JSON, it appears to decode up to a particular level and stops there. The output is below. You can clearly see that it creates an array and then stops, the rest is an in-iterable string. I wanted to loop over the response, creating a CSV output. [image]

```
$url = $request->url;
    
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 300000,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        // Set Here Your Requesred Headers
        'Content-Type: application/json',
    ),
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $data = json_decode($response, true);
    
    dd($data);
    JsonToCsv::exportCSV($data);
```

Please how do I properly parse this large JSON response?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Hmm, I suspect that at that point in the JSON there is some sort of encoding issue with the text it contains. I'd take a close look at the content in that first unexpected value. Ive seen similar issues when values in the JSON needed to be encoded via `utf8_encode` before running json_encode on the dataset

Comment: I can't even access that area of the response. It' like a line of string. How do i do the encoding and final decoding?

Comment: I would start by echoing out the full raw `$response` value and pasting it somewhere like [here](https://jsoneditoronline.org/) then reviewing that text for potential issues. If it is an encoding issue, it likely needs to be fixed at the source where the text is being json encoded and sent back from the API but that's where Id  start looking anyway.